# Find a strings in a cell and copy the found cell to a specific cell by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

need help in Excel VBA, please. I am trying to find a string in a cell and if found want to copy the cell to a specific cell, want to loop for next rows until end of data rows. I used the code as follows it find and copy but copy to the next cell, I need in a specific cell. Thank you.

```
    Sub TEST()

    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("B1:K100")
        If InStr(1, c.Text, "Address:") Then
            c.Copy Destination:=c.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
        End If
    Next c

    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific cell? is it different everytime "Address:" is found?

Comment: Change the destination.

Comment: @ManuelLemos, Yes, Address is different every time

Comment: what is the relationship between any given cell that hold "Address:" and the destination cell you want to copy to?

Comment: @i have tried with " desitination:= worksheets("Sheet1").range ("B1") "  but it failed

Comment: @ManuelLemos, both are in the same row

Comment: @ManuelLemos, Your codes works excellent, now please help in another search two strings "Address:" and "Phone:" please accept apologies, i should tell  at the beginning .

Comment: @HelloBD Probably best to make a new post friendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my guess at what you are attempting to do

```
Sub Test()

    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")

    Dim c As Integer, r As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer: lastRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' assumes your lowest piece of content will be in column 1
    Dim lastCol As Integer: lastCol = src.Cells(1, src.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' assumes your rightmost piece of content will be located in row 1
    Dim destinationCol As Integer: destinationCol = lastCol + 1

    For r = 1 To lastRow
        For c = 1 To lastCol
            If InStr(1, src.Cells(r, c).Value, "Address:") Then
                src.Range(src.Cells(r, c), src.Cells(r, c)).Copy Destination:=src.Range(src.Cells(r, destinationCol), src.Cells(r, destinationCol))
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Error, Method 'range' object_worksheet failed

Comment: I edited the code a few mins ago, try again.

Comment: Thank you very much it work excellent, but if i want to use Column name like "K" or any anyone

Comment: set the destinationCol to be whatever column you want. K is the 11th letter in the alphabet so you would set destinationCol = 11